# Is there a way to create templates for text files in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, text-files

In Eclipse, I really enjoy being able to create templates for things I commonly write in Java and XML.  While there is some room for improvement, templates have proven to be quite the time saver.  Today I was documenting some notes in the release notes.  We have a specific format that we write said release notes in.  I thought it would be handy to write a small template so that I could easily insert most of the boiler plate text when I amend the notes.  So I dug around the eclipse settings and didn't see anything for plain text files.  I googled around and also didn't see anything.

So is what I'm wanting to do possible in Eclipse?  Is there a plugin I would need to enable such a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the closest you can get is using *Snippets*

Add the view by clicking `Window` -> `Show View` -> `Snippets`. In that view, right-click and select `Customize`to create custom snippets. You can now add those snippets in your textfile by double-clicking them.
Maybe there is also some shortcut feature I didn't find yet...